# Django's truncatechars filter cuts off text in italics tag and makes everything on the page italic

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a blog in Django where the front page has to have the content of each article truncated.  I used {{ value | truncatechars:600 | safe}} cut off the text and I have 'read more' button right after it for those who want to read the rest.

```
{% for display in posts %}
<article>

    <div class="post-info">
        <h2><a href="{% url 'single' display.slug %}">{{ display.title }}</a></h2>
        <h3><strong>{{ display.subtitle }}</strong></h3>
        <h4>published {{ display.date_published }}</h4>
        <h4>by {{ display.author }}</h4>
    </div>

    {% if display.image %}
        <img class="post-image" src="{{ display.image.url }}">
    {% endif %}     

    <div class="body">
    {{ display.body | truncatechars:600 | safe }}<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{% url 'single' display.slug %}">read more</a>
    </div>

</article>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that I made an article where it truncates the text in the middle of an italic em tag and it therefore makes everything else on the page italic.

Is there another way to truncate the text even in the middle of a bold and italic section without it running into this dilemma?

Comment: Would removing all html tags work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`truncatechars_html`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html) which is intended for exactly such use cases:

> Similar to `truncatechars`, except that it is aware of HTML tags. Any tags that are opened in the string and not closed before the truncation point are closed immediately after the truncation.